# Can I import a gun-shaped console controller‎ from the United States into the UK?

Tags: air-travel, uk, luggage, legal, firearms

My friend is traveling to the states next week for a short time then he'll be back to England , I would love to ask him to get me [this](http://www.thedeltasix.com/) very unique xbox controller.

He doesn't have to carry it with him of course instead he will keep it in his luggage. Would it cause him any problems?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travelling.

Comment: To what country is it being transported, and where will it transit?

Comment: @MichaelHampton US to UK, direct flight.

Comment: And what's with the ad parameter in the link you posted?

Comment: "It is an offence for anyone to sell, import or manufacture a realistic imitation firearm. The maximum penalty for breaching the restriction is 6 months imprisonment and/or a £5,000 fine.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's game controller and it's 100% legal, I am only trying to save time and to avoid freaking out UK customs

Comment: What makes you believe it's "100% legal" in the UK?  Per dan1111's answer, "imitation firearms" of all kinds are prohibited, regardless of whether it's intended to be a replica or a game controller.

Comment: @jpatokal I am not sure about the UK but it seems legal in The US, I think I believe so much in our system in The UK and the freedom we enjoy.

Comment: In the US I can go to a shop and walk out in 15 minutes with a _real_ AR-15 rifle, magazines and ammunition. I'm not sure about the UK, but something tells me it would be much more difficult there.

Comment: Hey you have asked previous questions on carrying replica unarmed explosives, children toy guns and now this replica, which looks like a real gun ? Are your sure about what you are trying to know ?

Comment: It will probably cause problems. The real question is whether your friend is willing to defend his luggage and show it's harmless when asked to do so AND whether you're willing to risk it getting impounded anyway.

Comment: Per [the regulations stated in the answer below](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/67475/42587), this is easy enough to fix.  Have it spray painted neon pink before trying to import it - [$3.86 at Walmart](http://www.walmart.com/ip/37326882?wmlspartner=wlpa&adid=22222222227026594203&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=42974070272&wl4=&wl5=pla&wl6=81466249952&veh=sem).  Problem solved.

Comment: There are plenty of real guns that come in different colors, pink being one of the more usual. Painting it is not enough to distinguish a real from a fake gun.

Comment: Agreed.  However the point is not to distinguish it from a real gun.  The point is to make it fail the legal criterion for realistic gun replica.

Comment: The company that sells this controller has successfully shipped them internationally, (including AUS which has some very strict gun/fake-gun rules). They also have a policy that they will refund you if your controller isn't able to reach you because of Customs issues. Reach out to them directly and ask if they've had success shipping to the UK. It'd be better for them to take the heat of dealing with shipping to the UK rather than your friend.

Comment: @BobbyScon I can't thank you enough for this comment, it's the most productive response I have received today.

Comment: One thing - I know they created a version of the controller designed to be shipped to countries with stricter laws. Same controller, but in white and with a larger orange tip or something. Be sure to ask if what they're shipping is different from what's pictured above. I was a backer of this KS campaign, so I've seen comments from various international backers.

Comment: The answer is "yes , but". You need to look at the regulations covering air soft weapons and get the controller painted to comply with those. This means painting a large amount of if in a bright colour , the orange tip isn't enough. I would suggest approaching your local air soft supplier and seing if they can can import one for you and paint it according to the regulations

Comment: JUst gotta say, that is one awesome looking game controller. Unfortunately getting that through an airport is going to cause a huge problem. Even if it were allowed, seems like you'd end up with 3 strip searches, many hours of questioning and a possible tazeing or two before your friend got on the plane.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

IMHO the problem here is that **the UK law forbids importing imitation firearms**. Quoting from [the Guide on Firearms Licensing Law found on Gov.uk](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjy7-bYt7PMAhUHVhQKHewtB7cQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gov.uk%2Fgovernment%2Fuploads%2Fsystem%2Fuploads%2Fattachment_data%2Ffile%2F518193%2FGuidance_on_Firearms_Licensing_Law_April_2016_v20.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGsCln_nvobYzNAr5qYWg4vBZl3Uw):

> Section 36 of the Violent Crime Reduction Act 2006 makes it an offence for a person to manufacture, sell, import or cause a realistic imitation firearm to be brought into Great Britain.

As it turns out, [an imitation firearm is](http://www.cps.gov.uk/legal/d_to_g/firearms/#a01):

> any thing which has the appearance of being a firearm (other than such a weapon as is mentioned in section 5(1) (b) of this Act), whether or not it is capable of discharging any shot, bullet or other missile

Taken together, these two statements would make me think that **you cannot import a gun-shaped console controller into the UK**.

For completeness sake, note that [your friend is likely to be prosecuted under Section 170(2) of CEMA 1979](http://www.cps.gov.uk/legal/d_to_g/firearms/#a27):

> Section 170(2) of CEMA 1979 covers the import "smuggling" offence in so far as a person knowingly concerned in the fraudulent evasion or attempted evasion relating to goods (namely firearms) that are subject to any "prohibition or restriction." The prohibition upon the importation of firearms is contained in Article 1 of the Import of Goods (Control) Order 1954 (SI 1954/23) which was made under section 1 of the Import, Export and Customs Powers (Defence) Act 1939.

Comment: Does the last bit you quoted concern imitation firearms? It mentions only firearms. Also it would seem to apply only if the object is not declared to customs ("fraudulent evasion") and only if the person was aware that the importation was restricted ("knowingly"). It can be hard to prove that someone "knows" something.

Comment: @phoog Import of imitation firearms is restricted so yes I'd say this applies.

Comment: @phoog - in this case, not so hard. OP openly asked on a forum since he feels there may be some laws against it. Asking the question in a way eliminated any "I had no idea!" excuses if Customs Enforcement comes knocking.

Comment: @BruceWayne that assumes that customs enforcement would be able to connect this question with the defendant.

Comment: @phoog - oh for sure, just thought to mention it though.

Answer (score 41):

[Realistic toy guns are banned in the UK](http://www.cheshireeast.gov.uk/business/trading_standards/business_support/product_safety/imitation_firearms.aspx).
  Based on the information on that page, it seems quite likely that this would qualify and therefore be banned.  The penalty for trying to import it could be up to a £5000 fine or 6 month prison sentence.

This mainly hinges on whether this gun is considered "realistic".  In the U.S. an orange tip on a gun is sufficient to mark something as a toy, but [here is the relevant guideline from UK.gov](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/518193/Guidance_on_Firearms_Licensing_Law_April_2016_v20.pdf) (emphasis added):

> an imitation is to be regarded as distinguishable if its size, shape
>   or **principal colour** is unrealistic for a real firearm...
>
> An imitation firearm which
>   is **principally coloured** bright red, bright orange, bright yellow, bright green, bright pink,
>   bright purple, bright blue, or which is transparent should...be regarded as unrealistic

In addition, the controller is styled similar to a real gun and is of sufficient size (longer than 70mm) to qualify as realistic under the regulations.

Beyond that, I would not ask a friend to bring something that is likely to attract the attention of security.  Even if it were technically allowed, surely this is likely to attract attention and add extra hassle to travelling.

Comment: A replica is NOT the same as a game controller. I appreciate your answer this is exactly why I asked, I don't want to get him in trouble, maybe I was hoping for someone to tell me it's OK.

Comment: @Ulkoma, this is a toy that looks like a gun, and the law covers such toys.  The fact that it works as a game controller is not relevant.  The conditions for what make a fake gun "realistic" are listed in the link, and it seems quite clear that this would count as realistic.

Comment: Relevant quote from the article: *The basic test is to ask the question, “does the imitation gun look like a real firearm?”. If the answer is yes, then the item is likely to be a realistic imitation firearm and its sale, importation and manufacture is outlawed.*

Comment: @dan1111 Don't hesitate to add relevant quotes from the linked page into your answer. This way if the link goes down/changes we still have the information here.

Comment: @JoErNanO, thanks, I have added the bit about color, as this seems to be a point of debate.

Comment: Good answer, but it leads me to ask about airsoft guns here in the UK - most of them look realistic and are not produced in bright colours, and yet they are completely legal and sold throughout the UK?

Comment: @Lyall as per the link, airsoft is an exemption to the ban: "the organisation and holding of the acting out of military or law enforcement scenarios for the purpose of recreation, where the organiser holds public liability insurance for such events. This includes Airsoft skirmishing." However, in order to purchase airsoft guns you must be over 18 and have a valid defense (such as UKARA membership) - something to prove that you are an airsoft player, regularly skirmish and therefore have a reason to own it. :)

Comment: @Luna Thanks - I didn't follow the link sorry about that. Although you can buy airsoft guns online without any ID or proof of membership required (but you have to say you are over 18). I read that they produce about the same energy as a tennis ball being dropped from 1 meter in the air so I've never really worried about it.

Comment: @Lyall It is possible to buy airsoft guns online, but you should have a valid defence if you are challenged or asked. The airsoft industry basically has to police itself on that - it's down to the retailer to ask, but they should even if they don't always. It's more about the "looking like a gun" thing than the damage they can do (although they can do pretty bad damage to eyes or teeth in the wrong circumstances).

Comment: @Lyall And the kinetic energy of a 100 mph fastball is about the same as that of a pistol-fired .22, but, given the choice, I'd rather be hit by the baseball than shot with a .22. Of course, being hit by a 100 mph fastball will hurt a lot, but it's not likely to kill you. Total kinetic energy matters, but the area over which it's applied matters a lot more.

Comment: @Ulkoma To add to dan1111's point, if this resulted in a criminal prosecution the criterion would be "does it look like a gun *to the 12 randomly chosen UK citizens who happen to be serving on the jury, and most likely have never seen a real gun in their lives.*" Be warned, even a table leg wrapped in a plastic bag looks near enough like a gun to some people in the UK. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Harry_Stanley#Shooting